# Launching an X application on a remote server works when SSH'd but not as an inline command

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a remote server that I want to launch an X application on. I don't need to see the GUI myself (no x-forwarding), I just need to launch the app.

This works:

```
$ ssh <remotehost>
$ xapplicationname -params
```

This does not work:

```
$ ssh <remotehost> 'xapplicationname -params'
(xapplicationname:12939): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Why?

Inline commands do work for non-X applications, like

```
$ ssh <remotehost> 'ls -lar'
```

Ubuntu 17.10, stock configuration

Comment: ... the former will invoke a login shell, maybe that's a clue?

Comment: Not to a novice. I notice when I try and do 'export DISPLAY' in an inline ssh command that it returns a null string so I'm assuming that it's somehow related but this isn't my area of expertise, hence posting a question on SE.

Comment: When you do `ssh <remotehost>`, what is the output of `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: if I ssh first and then echo it, I get :1. If I ssh 'echo $DISPLAY' it's blank.

Comment: OK so you will need to establish *how* the variable is being set - some possibilities are (1) your login shell is invoking an X session (e.g. using `startx` in one of the startup files - `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`) (2) the login shell (again via one of the startup files) is checking for an existing X session and its associated display (3) the login shell is simply exporting `DISPLAY=:1` and hoping that there is a corresponding X session running

Comment: Aha, that did it. X was starting as part of the startup so I just have to ssh <ip> 'startxfce4; export DISPLAY=:1; <runApp>' and it works great. Thank you for the push in the right direction.